# How to deal with the "com.qualcomm.qtil.aptxui has stopped" error message?

Tags: system-error, bluetooth-audio

I have Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 android phone. Whenever I connect my bluetooth headphones and start playing music, I receive an error message saying "com.qualcomm.qtil.aptxui has stopped". The only option is to dismiss the error message and everything works fine then. What does the error message mean? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Same problem here, but I realized that it doesn't happen to any bluetooth device, but only to a few.ones, maybe those that are bluetooth 4.x. It's annoying, though.

Comment: Same problem here with zb631kl (Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2). No solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently gotten into the same issue regarding my Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1. It turns out that I discovered an option, right inside Bluetooth device settings, that disables aptX HD Audio, so it won't keep stopping. Make sure to keep "Media audio" checked whilst unchecking the problematic "HD Audio". It worked for me, as I stopped receiving the stop error.

[image]